# pandas interpolate with nearest neighbor returns new values

Tags: python, pandas, nearest-neighbor, resampling

I would like to upsample this data by using the nearest neighbor interpolation.

file.csv

```
ProcessStepId,_time
0,2019-03-14 01:35:59.769
0,2019-03-14 01:37:59.076
0,2019-03-14 01:39:59.723
0,2019-03-14 01:42:00.145
1,2019-03-14 01:42:04.478
1,2019-03-14 01:43:59.818
1,2019-03-14 01:45:59.776
1,2019-03-14 01:47:59.802
```

My approach up until now:
read the csv file into a dataframe and convert it into a DateTime indexed dataframe. Then upsample it and interpolate using nearest neighbor

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file.csv)
form = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_time'].dt.strftime(form), exact=False)
df.set_index('_time', inplace=True)

#Now upsample
df = df.resample('10s').mean()
df.interpolate(method='nearest', inplace=True)
```

My output looks like this:

```
_time,    ProcessStepId
2019-03-14 01:35:50, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:36:00, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:36:10, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:36:20, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:36:30, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:36:40, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:36:50, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:37:00, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:37:10, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:37:20, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:37:30, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:37:40, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:37:50, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:38:00, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:38:10, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:38:20, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:38:30, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:38:40, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:38:50, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:39:00, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:39:10, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:39:20, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:39:30, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:39:40, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:39:50, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:40:00, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:40:10, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:40:20, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:40:30, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:40:40, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:40:50, 0.0
2019-03-14 01:41:00, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:41:10, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:41:20, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:41:30, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:41:40, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:41:50, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:42:00, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:42:10, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:42:20, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:42:30, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:42:40, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:42:50, 0.5
2019-03-14 01:43:00, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:43:10, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:43:20, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:43:30, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:43:40, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:43:50, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:44:00, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:44:10, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:44:20, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:44:30, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:44:40, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:44:50, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:45:00, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:45:10, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:45:20, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:45:30, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:45:40, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:45:50, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:46:00, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:46:10, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:46:20, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:46:30, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:46:40, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:46:50, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:47:00, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:47:10, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:47:20, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:47:30, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:47:40, 1.0
2019-03-14 01:47:50, 1.0
```

I would expect all the `ProcessStepId` values to be equal to 1 or 0 (ideally integers), but here some rows have been assigned a value of 0.5 (which is not valid for my usecase). Furthermore, i'd expect any value after `2019-03-14 01:42:04.478` to be definitely equal to 1 which is not the case here.

Am I missing something about how nearest neighbor works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `df.resample(...).mean()` creates the 0.5 values. Just use nearest when doing the resampling to replace the missing values with the nearest neighbor from the sequence:

```
df = df.resample('10s').nearest()
```